# Lazy functions evaluation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

Wondering is it possible to evaluate a simple if statement lazily. Below is an example that will print "this is foo" and "this is bar", but I really want to make it print only the first string:

```
func foo() {
  println("this is foo")
}

func bar() {
  println("this is bar")
}

func maybeFooOrBar(isFoo: Bool) {
  let myFoo = foo()
  let myBar = bar()
  isFoo ? myFoo : myBar
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. This is a well asked question. I suspect it's because this just isn't possible. (I don't know that for certain else I would post that as an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not know if this is what you want,you can **use function as a type**

```
func foo() {
    println("this is foo")
}

func bar() {
    println("this is bar")
}

func maybeFooOrBar(isFoo: Bool) {
    let myFoo = foo
    let myBar = bar
    let result = isFoo ? myFoo : myBar
    result()
 }
```

Then if you `callmaybeFooOrBar(true)` will print first function,`callmaybeFooOrBar(false)`wii print second function

Also,this can be done in a clear way

```
func maybeFooOrBar(isFoo: Bool) {
    (isFoo ? foo : bar)()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find canonical proof that **Swift isn't a lazy evaluating language**, but I'm sure the community will correct me if I'm wrong!

Since it isn't lazy, the method calls are simply executed in order rather than determining which methods will never need to be called.

To achieve the same effect, you need to implement the "lazy" behaviour yourself.

```
if isFoo
{
    foo()
}
else
{
    bar()
}
```

or more simply:

```
isFoo ? foo() : bar()
```

---

Swift *does* have [lazy instantiation](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/). That is, you can tell it that variables shouldn't be instantiated until they are used.

In Objective-C, this would require the developer to implement this behaviour manually:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *players;
- (NSMutableArray *)players 
{
    if (!_players) 
    {
        _players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _players;
}
```

In Swift, this is much simpler and achieved using the `lazy` keyword:

```
lazy var players = [String]()
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this works fine. But it's really interesting to make it works like in my example

Comment: The problem with the example in your question is that it ignores the effect of the function invocation. Just because the result variable isn't used doesn't mean that the function invocation didn't do something else - in theory the compiler could attempt to determine whether the function invocation could be optimised out, but foo() or bar() could result in many additional function invocations and it rapidly becomes very difficult - much simpler for the programmer not to invoke the function if it isn't necessary

Comment: James, you can't pass arguments to lazy var initialization. This doesn't work if you're going to make most of your functions referential transparent.

Comment: yes, I see this. But the question was about lazy functions, not lazy vars. It's quite straightforward to open google or swift docs and find how to instantiate lazy var.

Comment: @RudraFury, I only included that because I thought you may have read about lazy instantiation, forgotten exactly what it was and then got it confused with lazy evaluation... I did ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very simple solution following leo's answer

```
func foo(a: Int)() {
  println("this is foo")
}

func bar(b: Int)() {
  println("this is bar")
}

func maybeFooOrBar(isFoo: Bool) {
  let myFoo = foo(1)
  let myBar = bar(2)
  isFoo ? myFoo() : myBar()
}
```